# How to read a LAS file using C#

Tags: c#, liblas

I need to read `LAS file` using `C#` and then convert it to `xml` using `C#` for my project. Any help would be appreciated.

I need to read the specific headers and Data under them. The headers basically start with ~ in the `LAS file`. I have worked on creating an `XML` using `C#`. But having problem in reading the `LAS file` using `C#`. I have tried using `libLAS` libraries available on net, but getting errors.

@17-06-2010

I am using the `libLAS` library into my project to read a LAS file and I am getting this error

```
(Unable to load DLL 'liblas1.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)).  Any help???
```

Comment: And what exactly is a LAS file?

Comment: its all ball-bearings these days, Ningraj

Comment: 1. Read your file. 2. Parse it. 3. Transform it to XML.
Any questions left?

Comment: I need to read the specific headers and Data under them.  The headers basically start with ~ in the LAS file.  I have worked on creating an XML using C#. But having problem in reading the LAS file using C#.  I have tried using libLAS libraries available on net, but getting errors. Any Help??

Comment: @Henk LAS File Format info can be found here : http://www.cwls.org/docs/LAS12_Standards.txt .
@Ningraj If you are getting crashes, it may be worth posting what they are and where they happen.

Answer (score 2):

This links to a c# tutorial on the liblas.org site http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/csharp.html . Hope this helps.  The latest release, libLAS-1.7.0b1 installs like a dream compared to the 1.6.1 nightmare (under windows). Chris

Answer (score 0):

WolfInSpace answered the second part of your question. You can find the answer to the first part in this thread:

[Is there an R package to parse geophysical "Log Ascii Standard" Files (.las files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804203/is-there-an-r-package-to-parse-geophysical-log-ascii-standard-files-las-file/19498739#19498739)

Moreover, in case you are into developing yourself, you can read this article on saving LAS files:

http://www.kgs.ku.edu/stratigraphic/PROFILE/HELP/Help-PC-SaveLASFile.html

Please let us know what did u end up doing. I am working on the same project as well.
Best

Comment: Link only answers are not nice, try to put in relevant code or summarize the process

Answer (score -1):

You can create an XML document quite easily in C# using XmlWriter, contained in the System.Xml namespace. Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XmlExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            students.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Name = "Ryan", Grade = 99 });
            students.Add(new Student { ID = 2, Name = "Ann", Grade = 84 });
            students.Add(new Student { ID = 3, Name = "Rebecca", Grade = 83 });
            students.Add(new Student { ID = 4, Name = "Jon", Grade = 26 });

            using (XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create("ComputerScience1234.xml"))
            {
                xml.WriteStartDocument();
                xml.WriteStartElement("COSC1234");

                foreach (Student s in students)
                {
                    xml.WriteStartElement("Student");

                    xml.WriteElementString("ID", s.ID.ToString());
                    xml.WriteElementString("Name", s.Name);
                    xml.WriteElementString("Grade", s.Grade.ToString());

                    xml.WriteEndElement();
                }

                xml.WriteEndElement();
                xml.WriteEndDocument();

            }
        }
    }
}
```