# Extract last word in string in R

Tags: r

What's the most elegant way to extract the last word in a sentence string?

The sentence does not end with a "."
Words are seperated by blanks.

```
sentence <- "The quick brown fox"
TheFunction(sentence)
```

should return: "fox"

I do not want to use a package if a simple solution is possible.
If a simple solution based on package exists, that is also fine.

Comment: Give us some details about your data structure, otherwise, we're just all stabbing in the dark while trying to help you out.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd imagine you can just reverse the string and separate by `" "`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093931/r-remove-last-word-from-string

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
tail(strsplit('this is a sentence',split=" ")[[1]],1)
```

Basically as suggested by @Señor O.

Comment: It's hard for me to call a method with `[[` elegant :) but that might be my personal feeling for R's lists

Answer (score 71):

Just for completeness: The library [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) contains a function for exactly this problem.

```
library(stringr)

sentence <- "The quick brown fox"
word(sentence,-1)
[1] "fox"
```

Answer (score 18):

```
x <- 'The quick brown fox'
sub('^.* ([[:alnum:]]+)$', '\\1', x)
```

That will catch the last string of numbers and characters before then end of the string.

You can also use the `regexec` and `regmatches` functions, but I find `sub` cleaner:

```
m <- regexec('^.* ([[:alnum:]]+)$', x)
regmatches(x, m)
```

See `?regex` and `?sub` for more info.

Comment: I'd say Roland's solution to this specific problem is much simpler, but your code provides a good template for doing all sorts of targeted extractions.

Comment: if you're looking to make the syntax even shorter, you can omit `^` (`sub` will start at the beginning on its own) and replace `[[:alnum:]]` with `\\w`

Comment: @eddi Good point.  However, I like to be as explicit as possible with regular expressions and only generalize as I find cases I miss rather than trying to find cases where I've over matched.

Comment: how would the regex be like if we extract the last N words, not just the last one ?

Comment: Thank you for providing a clean, base R answer. I want to learn regex, not just some clever wrapper for it!!

Answer (score 13):

Another packaged option is `stri_extract_last_words()` from the `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)

stri_extract_last_words("The quick brown fox")
# [1] "fox"
```

The function also removes any punctuation that may be at the end of the sentence.

```
stri_extract_last_words("The quick brown fox? ...")
# [1] "fox"
```

Answer (score 5):

Going in the package direction, this is the simplest answer I can think of:

```
library(stringr)

x <- 'The quick brown fox'
str_extract(x, '\\w+$')
#[1] "fox"
```