# R replace string-matching in dataframe with value from another dataframe with gsub

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching, gsub

```
text = c("Hello abc01","Go to abc02")
value = c(0,1)
symbol=c("abc01","abc02")
df1 = data.frame(text)
df2 = data.frame(symbol,value)
```

I want to replace the symbols contained as text in df1 with the corresponding value in df2, to obtain: `'Hello 0', 'Go to 1'`.

Typically for string-replacement I used gsub(pattern, replacement, x)

Ex: If I want to replace "abc01" and "abc02" with "OK":

```
df1 = apply(df1,2,function(x) gsub("abc[0-9]{2}","OK",x))
```

My idea is to use a function in replace section:

```
gsub(df1,2,function(x) gsub("(abc)", Support(KKK),x)
```

in which I'll do the substitution, but I don't know how I can passing as argument KKK, the matching-strings determined(abc01,abc02).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Could try `library(gsubfn) ; gsubfn("abc0(\\d)", ~ as.integer(x) - 1, text)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Good catch.  In that case, maybe `stri_replace_all_fixed(text, df2$symbol, df2$value, vectorize_all = FALSE)`?

Comment: @Jota, Yeah it would be the ideal solution I guess. No need to use the `data.frame` neither. Just `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(text, symbol, value, vectorize_all = FALSE)`. You could post that.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you all for your help. This is a simple example, but in my research I need to keep everything in dataframe. My solution:    `(library(gsubfn) ; f = function(x) {return (subset(df2,subset=(symbol==x),select=value))} ; df1 = apply(df1,2,function(x) gsubfn("abc[0-9]{2}", f, x))`

Comment: Why can't you simply use @Jota s solution? It is simple and very efficient

Comment: @DavidArenburg 'cause in my dataframe df1 has more than one column, and do `df1 = stri_replace_all_fixed(text, symbol, value, vectorize_all = FALSE)` it causes loss of information.

Comment: @M.T. you would assign the results to a single column (e.g. `df1[["newText"]] <- stri_replace_blah_blah(blah)`), and not overwrite the entire dataframe.

Comment: @Jota Thanks , I started using R from this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea (not as slick as the one in comments). What this does, it basically replaces the last word of `df1$text` with the `df2$value` of the matched `df2$symbol`

```
sapply(df1$text, function(i) 
       gsub(paste(df2$symbol, collapse = '|'), 
                df2$value[match(sub('^.* ([[:alnum:]]+)$', '\\1', i), df2$symbol)], i))

#[1] "Hello 0" "Go to 1"
```

P.S. I borrowed the `sub('^.* ([[:alnum:]]+)$', '\\1', i)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658216/extract-last-word-in-string-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1[["text"]] <- stri_replace_all_fixed(text, symbol, value, vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Thanks Jota for the solution.